# Geometric meaning of the $C^1$ norm

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Can someone explain the geometric meaning of the $C^1$ norm on $C^1[X]$, where $X$ is compact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $X$ a manifold?

Comment: Yes, X is a compact manifold